# SQL Server training materials

Tags: sql-server

I'm sorry if this question breaks the rules of DBA StackExchange. I'm not sure if it is allowed in here.

I am planning to lead a basic SQL Server training for my coworkers. The course should include some basic information about relational databases and the SQL querying. This is why I'm looking for some training materials.

Obciously I could prepare PowerPoint presentations, SQL tasks and all the other stuff myself but I think since it is a well researched topic I should not reinvent the wheel.

Do you know of any training materials available that I could use?
I have the training materials for the MS Exam 70-461 - Querying SQL Server but I'm not sure if I would be allowed to use it and also they are pretty big.

Can you recommend something?

Answer (score 3):

Try my free [Learn to Query SQL Server with the Stack Overflow Database](https://www.brentozar.com/learn-query-sql-server-stackoverflow-database/).

You can either run the queries locally with the [Stack Overflow SQL Server data export](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/), or through your browser with [Data.StackExchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I thought Brent Ozar was a busy man. And here he comes answering my question withing 2 minutes of asking it. Thanks for the link, it will probably a great way of leading the training

Comment: HAHAHA, you're welcome. Yeah, our company Slack has a notification for new DBA.se questions, and I had a few minutes. :-D